# check if primary key exist

Tags: c#

I have tried posting this earlier and had to delete it because the code editor did not post it correctly and incompletely. plus I had a member ask me about SQL injection.

Here's the story:

I have a page where the user can check his information before it is submitted to the database. All I want to do is look to see if that primary key is present before I submit it to avoid getting a server error.

In my page load event I have the following:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand oldcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from dbo.registrar WHERE [MY ID] = '"+ID+"'", conn);
oldcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(oldcmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
{
   lblExists.Visible = true;
   lblExists.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   lblExists.Text = "Oops! Our records show that you have already signed up for this service. Please check your information or contact your administrator for further assistance.";
}
```

The label fires even though there is no record in the database which tells me that I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Is the label definitely invisible before this code runs? Have you tried putting a breakpoint here and using the debugger to see what the data returned from the database actually is?

Comment: What is `ID` type and value in the scenario you're using?

Comment: You have 2 solutions, create a primary key with autoincrement, or create a storedproc to verify if all conditions is ok and select data. This is more secure because sql injection.

Comment: If you are trying to prevent any errors regarding to duplicate primary keys and still want to assign your own key, you can catch db exceptions. That way you won't need to check every time you are doing an insertion or update operation.

Comment: You still haven't answered the point about SQL injection...

Comment: My solution addresses the SQL injection issue.

Comment: how do i sanitize the injection?

Comment: @ObadiahWilliams: Brendan has sanitized the input in his answer, it's a good example and a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
SqlCommand oldcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.registrar WHERE [MY ID] = @id", conn);
oldcmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
oldcmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = ID;

if ((int)oldcms.ExecuteScalar() >= 1)
{
    lblExists.Visible = true;
    lblExists.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lblExists.Text = "Oops! Our records show that you have already signed up for this service. Please check your information or contact your administrator for further assistance.";
}
else
{
    lblExists.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: that worked. thanks! but now I when I hit the previous button in the wizard it throws me to the first step...not sure why

Comment: That seems to be outside the scope of this question.  Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem.